# running away button keeps leaving browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem. I am trying to program running away button, but it keeps leaving browser window. Is there any way how to set some limitations to random movement? I am trying to add this button to Adobe MUSE website... ANY IDEAS PLEASE? Thanks!

```html
<input onclick="location.href='http://www.besyx.sk/PF2017/gratulujeme.html';"
value="CHCEM ZVÝŠIŤ ADRENALÍN" 
style="transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; 
background: rgb(48, 197, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; 
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
height: 50px; 
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 153, 179); 
border-radius: 100px; 
padding-left: 20px; 
padding-right: 20px; 
margin-left: 0px; 
margin-top: 0px; 
margin-bottom: 0px;" 
onmouseover="this.style.marginLeft=Math.random()*400+event.clientX/8+'px'; this.style.marginTop=Math.random()*400+event.clientY/8+'px';" type="button">
```

Comment: button.style.left = Math.min(document.body.offsetWidth - button.offsetWidth, Math.random()*400+whatever) + 'px'

Comment: You should verify the new random location is not still beneath the mouse.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please paste it directly into my code for me?? I am very new to coding and syntax is not so obvious for me :)